# AddClass in mouseenter not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got this problem, I've a UL with some LIs and what I want it to do is: add the class "focused" when I enter the mouse in the LI and remove it to the previous one. So here is the code:

HTML:

```
<ul id="txtHint">
    <li class="focusable focused">Jack</li>
    <li class="focusable">Jone</li>
    <li class="focusable">Junita</li>
    <li class="focusable">Joleen</li>
    <li class="focusable">Jeniffer</li>
    <li class="focusable">Jacquie</li>
    <li class="focusable">Jin</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
  $("li.focusable").mouseenter(function () {
        $("li.focused").removeClass("focused");
        $(this).addClass("focused");
    });
```

CSS:

```
.focused {
    background-color: gray !important;
    color: white;
}
```

I hope someone could find the problem! Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qGNu/1/

Comment: using JS for a plain hover-effect is not wise.
use CSS event based selectors instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You missed to include the jQuery library
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cCX4r/)

Comment: Thanks! I'm very noob at jsfiddle... :D

Answer (score 1):

You only forgot to include jQuery library.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use this css:

```
.focusable:hover {
    background-color: gray !important;
    color: white;
}
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2EeB2/1/

Comment: Yes this is ok but what I want it to do is that .focused is background-color: gray;